How to redirect a reference to another assembly?
In MAUI application I add a reference to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in order to work with SQL Server. I also add a Dataset and create some dataadapters. Designer generates the code where it references System.Data.SqlClient, which accordingly are all unresolved. Is there a way to "redirect" all references of System.Data.SQLClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, assuming that all objects and members are the same?
Alternatively, is there a way to make dataset designer generate the code using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient ?

BTW I never connect to any sql server direct from a customer app (desktop or mobile) - I use a WebApi between them

This is internal company application for the warehouse, performing database transactions, accordingly reliability and encapsulation of sql statements in begin/commit block is #1 requirement. It seems to me the less hops, the more reliability.

Found the answer to part 2: the choice between system.data.sqlclient and microsoft.data.sqlclient is made at the time of specifying the connection/data source.
